# Sharepoint 2016 App Deployment error <nativehr>0x80010135

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

Sharepoint 2016 There was a problem with activating the app web definition

> `<nativehr>0x80010135</nativehr>`

Have not been able to find out what the error code means or a fix for it. Any help would be awesome

Comment: Found the issue, it was a corrupted file in the deployment package.  Error code 0x80010135 appears to reference "the filename is too long"